# How to Convert string to Long integer in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I can't use "`Int64.Parse(), Convert.ToInt64 and long.parse`" to convert string to long. when I debug, I get error `Input string was not in a correct format.`
What must I do. I can't solve the problem, when I try to solve, I don't have idea.
You can help me???
please, I hope you can help my problem.

Comment: What is the value of the string you are trying to convert? It sounds like it's not a valid long. You can always use Int64.TryParse if you aren't sure it's going to be a valid long. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int64.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Why do you need to convert string to long?
You can't convert string to long. Look at the basics of these data types. string can be set of characters. Long data type can't hold characters.So, its not allowed

Answer (score 0):

you can convert the string to long unless it doesn't have any alphabet or special characters. can you post the values which you try to convert?

Comment: I try with this to convert string to long, that string i get value from javascript popup 
public JsonResult ListDealer(DataMPMDISProposal item, List<string> DataDealer, string Distr)
{
long Kcm = Convert.ToInt64(Distr);
DISModel.Module.MPMDISRINGAREA disring = (new DISModel.Lov.Proposal.LovProposalObject()).GetRingArea(Convert.ToInt64(item.KecamatanID));
}